# Adding many projects outputs to the Setup project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, setup-project

I have about 60 projects in the solution. I want to add them as projects outputs to the Setup project. Is there any way to do it without adding all projects one by one?

Comment: How else do you propose to do it?

Comment: Just asking, maybe there is some more efficient way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to look at the vdproj file for one added project and try to replicate it of the other projects.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add them one by one